# Naming convention for OLP Protobuf Schemas

Tags: java, proto, here-olp

I'm trying to migrate some of our existing schema to OLP, using maven archetype. Is there any naming convention to what the package name should look like? We are debating wether it should be "com.here.hdlm.protobuf.schema" or "com.here.schema.hdlm.protobuf". Or maybe we should even skip protobuf from the name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use the convention of placing the project name after the reversed internet domain and company name, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html,
i.e., "com.here.hdlm"

As to whether "protobuf.schema", "schema.protobuf" or skipping protobuf, it's up to you.

As an additional reference - 
https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/data-user-guide/portal/schemas-creating.html

Answer (score -1):

HERE Artifact Service hosts only Protobuf Schemas. I would recommend not to use words 'protobuf' and 'schema' in the name as it is implied and makes the package name longer.

Protobuf Schema publishing documentation has a section connected to the naming: https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/archetypes/dev_guide/topics/archetypes-best-practices.html

This is the content of the section:

> **Package Naming**
>
> You are prompted to define the group ID, artifact ID, and package name
>   for your schema at the stage of generating a schema project. If you
>   don't specify any package name, the group ID is used instead.
>
> Group ID and artifact ID are used to generate the schema's HERE
>   Resource Name (HRN) once you upload your schema to OLP. For example,
>   the HRN of the HMC Building Footprints schema is
>   hrn:here:schema:::com.here.schema.rib:building-footprints_v2:2.13.0.
>
> The package name is used in the protobuf, Java, and Scala package
>   names.
>
> For group ID, use your company's reversed domain name, such as
>   com.here.schema.rib.
>
> For artifact ID, use a name specific to the type of schemas packaged
>   in the project, such as building-footprints. Try to keep the artifact
>   ID as short as possible.
>
> Also, make sure that the major version of your schema is included in
>   the name of your package. For example, version 2.3 should have v2 as
>   part of its package name, such as: com.here.platform.schema.foo.v2.
>   The presence of the major version in the package name is additionally
>   verified by the Major Version in Package Validator.
>
> We recommend following Java package naming conventions.